# bootbox.js callback don't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, bootbox

On bootbox documentation is stated that:

```
bootbox.alert(str message, fn callback)
```

where **message** = Default button text and **callback** = callback invoked on dismissal

If I understood that well, the callback function should be executed when the alert is closed, but when I use this code in the form of `bootbox.alert("test message", alert("callback"))` the callback alert pops up when invoking the bootbox, not on closure. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
bootbox.alert("test msg", function () { alert("callback here"); })
```

Comment: You won the race, +1 :) *edit* - why has someone downvoted this?

Comment: that worked, thank you a lot! But could you explain why this works and my method doesn't work? Strange thing is that it works as it invokes the function, but not when it needs to be invoked. I would love to know the reason of why should I add function() before ;)

Comment: @CornezuelodelCenteno bootbox uses call function on passed parameter. Functions are objects that have call method, but alert function is only a void function.

Comment: I don't think I understand it... How is that alert is a void function?

Answer (score 0):

```
bootbox.alert("test message!", function() {
 alert("callback!");
});
```